# How to Make Video Effects in PHP?

Tags: php, video-editing

Do you know of a way in php to do multitrack video editing? The only tool I have found online is a [MltMelt](http://mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/MltMelt), which is a command line utility.
I'm in the process of making an app that merges multiple videos, photos and audio clips into one video, but I was wondering if there was a way to process this in php. Can anyone point me to a PHP library that can handle things like multitrack merging, transitions, color effects, blurring, etc?

I'm looking for adobe premier like features in code.